# why does ReadString["fname",term] open a persistent stream, and how to close it?

Tags: bugs, import, core-language, documentation

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.3.0**

---

Create a file `temp.txt` with the following content:

```
test1
;;;
test2
;;;
test3
;;;
```

Treating the semicolon sequence as terminator, try to repeatedly read to the first terminator.

```
Table[ReadString["temp.txt", "\n;;;"], 6]
```

Contrary to my intent, this does *not* create a list holding "test1" 6 times.  Instead, it keeps reading the file to the next terminator, and starts over when it reached the end-of-file.

1. How can I understand the documentation to imply this behavior?
2. Is there a stream object hiding somewhere? (It is not listed by `Streams[]`.) If so, can it be closed?
3. How can I most simply achieve the desired behavior?  (Most simply means something more aesthetic than the following.)

..

```
Table[x = ReadString["C:/temp/temp.txt", ";;;"]; 
  ReadString["C:/temp/temp.txt"]; StringTrim[x], 6]
```

Comment: which version are you seeing this with? For me with 10.3.0 on Windows 7 it gives 6 times "test1" as expected (well it gives me "test1\r" but that's no surprise as I created the file on windows...)

Comment: "10.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)"

Comment: I have the same problem in 10.1.0.  Since the behavior was changed in 10.3.0 perhaps this is a bug and should be tagged as such?

Comment: I can confirm that the behavior with 10.2.0, 10.1.0 and 10.0.2 (`ReadList` was new in v10 I think) is as Alan describes while it is as he expects in 10.3.0, both on the same Windows 7 (64bit) machine. So it looks like it is a bug which has been corrected for 10.3.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I can confirm that in 10.3 the behaviour is as Albert describes. I have added the bugs tag.